# Set jdbc interceptor using DriverManager class

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-web-services, jdbc, aws-xray

I am using `DriverManager.getConnection(url, prop)` to get the connection. I am trying to inject the jdbc interceptors using properties like below but it is not working.

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
...
prop.setProperty("jdbcInterceptors", "com.amazonaws.xray.sql.mysql.TracingInterceptor;");
```

However, when we try to do via datasource it is working.

```
import org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource;
DataSource source = new DataSource();
source.setUrl("url");
source.setUsername("user");
source.setPassword("password");
source.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
source.setJdbcInterceptors("com.amazonaws.xray.sql.mysql.TracingInterceptor;");
```

Not sure what is wrong with `DriverManager` properties.

Comment: What is the fully qualified name of that `DataSource`?

Comment: added in the question

Answer (score 3):

These interceptors are a feature of the Tomcat `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy` and its subclass `org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource`. This is not a feature of JDBC itself, nor a feature of the JDBC driver you're using, so the only way to access it is through a Tomcat data source.

In short, it doesn't work with `DriverManager` because this feature doesn't exist in `DriverManager`.